# How to create a dynamic SELECT drop-down list in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to display the all the department names in the Dept Table in a combo box.
I have a function which fetches all the Dept name.
How can I dynamically create combo box in runtime, using javaScript or jQuery.

**HTML CODE**

```
     <select id="searchDepartments">
     </select> <input type="button" value="Search" onClick="search();" />
```

**JavaScript function**

```
function getDepartments(){
EmployeeManagement.getDeptList(function(deptList/*contains n-(dept.id, dept.name)*/{
    for(i = 0; i<deptList.length; i++){
```

How can I able to write a code that generates(adds) options to the list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The process is to create an `option` node for each item in the list, and add it as a child  of the `select` element.

In plain javascript:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('searchDepartments');
var opt = null;

for(i = 0; i<deptList.length; i++) { 

    opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.value = deptList[i].id;
    opt.innerHTML = deptList[i].name;
    sel.appendChild(opt);
}
```

Comment: U could declare the opt var inside the for loop

Answer (score 1):

There's a [plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/DDComboBox) that already does this, you may want to check it out.  Another benefit of this plugin, is that it has autocomplete built in.

> A drop-down combo box, or a select box
>   into which you can type text to narrow
>   down the visible result set. This code
>   is a compilation of the JQuery
>   Autocomplete plugin as well as other
>   JQuery plugins, and is still in the
>   alpha stage of development.

Answer (score 1):

A plain and simple JavaScript script would look as follows:

```
function AddOption(comboBoxID, displayText, displayValue)
{
    var optionItem = document.createElement("option");

    optionItem.text = displayText;
    optionItem.value = displayValue;

    document.getElementById(comboBoxID).options.add(optionItem);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following generic function:

```
function addOption(text,value,cmbId) {
    var newOption = new Option(text, value);
    var lst = document.getElementById(cmbId);
    if (lst) lst.options[lst.options.length] = newOption;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a datalist new option in html5:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="your_id" list="your_list" 
placeholder="Status"/>
<datalist id="your_list">
</datalist>
```

and fill it with a jquery .append function:

```
for(var i=0, len=resultado.response['id'].length; i<len; i++) 
{
    list += '<option value="' +resultado.response['data'][i]+" ( "+resultado.response['id'][i]+" ) "+ '"></option>';
}
dataList.html(list);
```