# how to use same json for populating two combobox?

Tags: jquery, json, combobox

I have two combobox and one url which is sending me json data to populate inside the combobox. How can I use same url to populate the combobox.

```
 `Can I use` $(".loctype").autocomplete({

source: function(request, response){

$.ajax..
}

});
```

I am not sure whether this is possible or not. I will appreciate if someone point me toward right direction.

my html code :

```
<p>
            <label for="ltype">Location Type</label>
            <select id="loctype">
            <option value="1">Warehouse</option>
            <option value="2">New Burg</option>

            </select>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="sku">Pallet Status</label>
            <select id="pstatus">
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>

            </select>
        </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your exact question, but if you return multiple fields:

```
return Json(new { Result = "success", location = whatever.location_id, status = whatever.pstatus });
```

You can assign:

```
if (data.Result == "success") {
      $('#loctype').val(data.location);
      $('#pstatus').val(data.status); 
}
```

**EDIT** I assumed you were sending back the selected value.  To add an option to the dropdown, you would need to return the text and value.

```
$('#loctype').append($('<option></option>').val(data.location_id).html(data.location_name));
```

If you also want that new value to be selected, append `.attr("selected", true)`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Jquery to populate a combobox. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600593/how-to-create-combo-box-in-runtime).

After getting json data, you can iterate through it and populate your comboboxes. Let's say that your data is like the following:

```
data = {'loctype':["Warehouse", "New Burg"], 'pstatus':[3,4]};
```

Now let's iterate through it and populate lists:

```
for(var i=0; i < data.loctype.length; i++) { // loctype and pstatus arrays have same length
    addOption(data.loctype[i], data.loctype[i], "loctype");
    addOption(data.pstatus[i], data.pstatus[i], "pstatus ");

}
```

The method, addOption is as follows:

```
function addOption(text,value,cmbId) {
  var newOption = new Option(text, value);
  var lst = document.getElementById(cmbId);
  if (lst) lst.options[lst.options.length] = newOption;
}
```