# How to update a dropdown list dynamically using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have a dropdown list which is initially empty:

```
 <div>
  <label>Boarding Point </label>
        <select title="Select pickup city"  id="boardingDropdown">
        
        </select>
</div>
```

I want to update it from the json data obtained from an API.
I can print the data obtained from API in the console, but I cannot
add it to the dropdown using jquery.

here is my jquery code

```
$.getJSON(busApi, function(boardingPoints) {
            $.each(boardingPoints, function(index, value){
                let $boardingOption = $("<option>" + value + "</option>");
                $("#boardingDropdown").append($boardingOption);
            });
        });
```

The dropdown just shows `undefined` without any other data.

I have tried other similar questions (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814512/how-to-create-dropdown-list-dynamically-using-jquery) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600593/how-to-create-a-dynamic-select-drop-down-list-in-javascript-jquery)) but they did not solve my problem.

Could somebody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

console.log(value) shows the output

```
Kathmadnu
Birgunj
Pokhariya
Langadi Chowk
Bhiswa
Birgunj
```

which is the expected output from the api.

I created a list with this data

```
let buses=["Kathmadnu",
            "Birgunj",
            "Pokhariya",
            "Langadi Chowk",
            "Bhiswa",
            "Birgunj"
          ];
```

Now the list still show `undefined` initially, but if I click on it, it shows the dropdown list as expected.

Does it mean there is problem with the API? But I can see the data obtained from the API in the console?

Comment: a write ```$("#boardingDropdown").length``` in console.log and what result?

Comment: @A.R.SEIF the answer shows 1

Comment: is Log inside ‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍‍```$.each‍‍‍```?

Comment: I tested for both inside and outside $.each. It shows 1 in both places.

Comment: a tested with Ready list.what result?example [1,2,3,4,5,6]

Comment: can you add response from the bus API here ? `console.log(value)` and add in your quesiton

Comment: @A.R.SEIF @ AlwaysHelping I've updated the question. Plz have a look.

Comment: @dhakalkumar i look a with ready list and work.for find problem ```console.log(boardingPoints)```.is Array?

Comment: @dhakalkumar all good i have deleted my working answer since it did to solved your particular issue. But its working fine here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the problem:**

I had given id to the <select> tag and was adding the options to this tag.

```
 <select title="Select pickup city"  id="boardingDropdown">
    
 </select>
```

Instead, what I did was to create a <div> tag above the <select> tag, and append <select>, then <option> and then </select> from the jquery.

```
<div>
    <label>Boarding Point </label>
        <div id="boardingDropdown"></div>
</div>
```

Then in the jquery, I appended the <select> tag as well:

```
$.getJSON(busApi, function (boardingPoints) {
    let opt = '<select>';
        $.each(boardingPoints, function (index, value){
            opt += '<option value="' + index + '">' + value + '</option>';
        });
        opt += '</select';
        $("#boardingDropdown").append(opt);
});
```

Now it is working as expected. `:)`

Comment: There is much better and clean approach then this one. Let me know if you want to know that - i will post an answer

Comment: Did my solution helped ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
let $boardingOption = $("<option>" + value + "</option>");
```

you should use:

```
let boardingOption= "<option>" + value + "</option>";
```

And in your code:

```
$(#boardingDropdown").append($boardingOption);
```

you missed a quote mark, it should be: `$("#boardingDropdown")`

---

Finally, according to my corrections, it should become:

```
$("#boardingDropdown").append(boardingOption);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer but that did not work. The list still shows undefined. And that typo of quote mark is in this question only which I have corrected.

Comment: your value in the your $.each function is not returning a value as at the time it appends to the select list, inspect in your browser using developer tools, and put breakpoints to check if your parameter "value" indeed has a value or its undefined

Comment: As I already said in the question I can print the values in the console but they are not visible in the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
$.each(items, function (i, value) {
    $('#boardingDropdown').append($('<option>', { 
        value: value_value,
        text : text_value 
    }));
});
```

The output should be something like this:

```
<select title="Select pickup city" id="boardingDropdown">
  <option value="value_value">text_value</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your solution says _Uncaught ReferenceError: value_value_ is not defined
 in the console.

Comment: you have to replace value_value  and text_value  to your variables name.
in your case is just "value".

example:
$.each(items, function (i, value) {
    $('#boardingDropdown').append($('<option>', { 
        value: value,
        text : value
    }));
});